# When voting to close the "content policy" link goes to a error 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, vote-to-close, closed-proposals

When I go to the "vote to close" option I see an option to close for content policy violation.
This link is http://area51.stackexchange.com/content-policy but it results in an error 404.

Please define the Content Policy so this close reason is understood by all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed. It just links to [Stack Overflow's content policy page](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/content-policy) for now.